# Resized image not saving

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload an image using storage folder, and also using traits, but when it comes using Intervention i'm really having trouble where to use it.
Here's the FileUploadTrait.php

```
public function uploadImage($image) {

if ($image) {

  $image_name = $image->store('public');
  $name = explode("/", $image_name);
  $img_name = $name[count($name) - 1];
  return $img_name;
}
return null;}}
```

ProjectsControler.php

```
  public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
      'image' =>'required|image|dimensions:min_width=800,min_height=600'
    ));

    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {

        $img_name= $this->uploadImage($request->image);

        $image_resize = Image::make($request->image);
        $image_resize->resize(800, 600);

    }


    $projects = Project::create(
      array_merge(
        $request->except('image', '_token'),
        ["image"=>$img_name ?? null]
        )
      );

      return redirect('my/path');
}
```

the image gets uploaded but not resized.

Comment: `$image_resize =  $image_resize->resize(800, 600);` instead of `$image_resize->resize(800, 600)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upload and resizing you have also to save the image to a given destination.

```
 if ($request->hasfile('image')) {

        $img_name= $this->uploadImage($request->image);

        $image_resize = Image::make($request->image);
        $image_resize->resize(800, 600)->save('Your Path');

    }
```

Comment: that's awesome, i tried to add ->save but the problem was that i did't gave right path for that image. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

You’re not saving your new resized image.

```
$image_resize->save();
```